# Rails: Template is missing / one method for handling POST and GET requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am a Rails newb, and am simply trying to flash an error, on a view with a form. When I sent a POST request to the path of the view I would like to flash the error on, my `routes.rb` file sends the POST request to my `update` method in my SchoolApplicationsController. However `update` is viewless so when I make the POST request to go there, and I meet an error case, I get Template is missing from my Rails Server.

The view where I would like to flash the error is the view which made the request to POST called the `pay` method in the same controller. What is the common practice here? Do I route the POST for the form submission to the same method as I would do the GET for the `pay` view, so that any flash errors can be presented in the desired place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To render a view in a "viewless" action you need to use the `render` method. In your case `render :pay`. It will render the form, already filling all the fields, filled previously (if you match the instance variables right).
2. To flash errors in that form you may use one of several options. First is to simply use `flash.now['error'] = 'Whatever error message you need'` before you do the rendering. Second is using the `.errors` method in the instance variable you are updating from the form. Look up the docs or use the console to look up what data that method provides.